# How to make facebook app use full screen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a facebook app and I want my app to use full screen in facebook iframe without any right sidebar which contains info about other apps. Is there any setting/code to remove it or is it default for all the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook take consideration about this once. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/436162913102704?browse=search_5046c9a1032a58d19137888